# How to prevent the loading every time when navigate

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a list view that shows images, every time i navigate to another screen and come back its reload the images.
i tried `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` but didn’t work.

this is the list

```
ListView.builder(
                  addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: allproducts.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                      value: allproducts[index],
                      child: const FeedsWidget(),
                    );
                  },
                ),
```

this is the screen that i call inside it

```
class FeedsWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const FeedsWidget({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FeedsWidget> createState() => _FeedsWidgetState();
}

class _FeedsWidgetState extends State<FeedsWidget>with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  final qantityController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    final themeState = Provider.of<DarkThemeProvider>(context);

    final ProductModelsvar = Provider.of<ProductModels>(context);
    final cartProvider = Provider.of<CartProvider>(context);
    bool? _isInCart =
        cartProvider.getCartItems.containsKey(ProductModelsvar.id);
    final wishListProvider = Provider.of<WishListProvider>(context);
    bool? _isInWishlist =
        wishListProvider.getwishListItems.containsKey(ProductModelsvar.id);

    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [

        Container(
          height: 230,
          width: double.maxFinite,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          ),
          child: Stack(alignment: Alignment.centerRight, children: [
            Container(
              width: double.maxFinite,
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                 child:CachedNetworkImage(
                   imageUrl:ProductModelsvar.imageUrl,
                   imageBuilder: (context,imageProvider)=>Container(

                     decoration: BoxDecoration(
                       image: DecorationImage(
                         image: imageProvider,
                         fit: BoxFit.cover,
                       ),
                     ),
                   ),
                   placeholder: (context,url)=>Container(
                     alignment: Alignment.center,
                     child:  LoadingManegar(isLoading: true),
                   ),

                 ),
                // Image.network(
                //   ProductModelsvar.imageUrl,
                //   fit: BoxFit.cover,
                //   loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child,
                //       ImageChunkEvent? loadingProgress) {
                //     if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
                //     return Center(
                //       child: LoadingManegar(
                //         isLoading: true,
                //       ),
                //     );
                //   },
                // ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: 80,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: Radius.circular(
                      20,
                    ),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(
                      20,
                    )),
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    child: ReusibleText(
                      text: ProductModelsvar.title,
                      size: 15,
                      textfontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  PriceWidget(
                    price: double.parse(ProductModelsvar.price),
                    textprice: '1',
                  ),
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: _isInCart
                            ? null
                            : ()async {
                              await  CartProvider.addToCart(
                                    productid: ProductModelsvar.id,
                                    quantity: 1, context: context);
                              await cartProvider.fetchCart();
                                // cartProvider.addProductToCart(
                                //     productid: ProductModelsvar.id,
                                //     quantity: 1);
                              },
                        icon: Icon(_isInCart ? Icons.check : IconlyLight.bag,
                            color: Colors.white,size: 20,),
                      ),
                      HeartWidget(
                        productId: ProductModelsvar.id,
                        isInwishList: _isInWishlist,
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pushNamed(context, "ProductDetScreen",
                              arguments: ProductModelsvar.id);
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(IconlyLight.arrowRightCircle,
                            color: Colors.white,size: 20),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ]),
        ),
      ],
    );

  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Comment: when you wants to get back to a page you came from, just use ```Navigator.pop(context);``` instead of pushing again (if you're).

Comment: i know bro, but i mean in the navigation bar if go to the cart screen and come back it reload the images

Comment: Yeah I know the pain of using navigation bar. I prefer ```TabBar()``` for the above reason.

Comment: so, u are telling me to switch to tab bar

Comment: If you can, Why not give it a try?